# images in a jar not found on a deployed application

Tags: java, spring, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have an application that generates a pdf report and load images on the pdf report, when i run the code on the IDE works perfectly, but when the app is deployed the images don't appear on the pdf report. The images are located in jar file, which is executable on the IDE, but when I have installed the app as a windows service the the images are not found in the classpath specified on the code.

I have declared a static string variable like this

```
public static final String IMAGES = "classpath:META-INF/images/%s.png";
```

on the classpath i tried specifying like this `"classpath*: "` still does not work.

and I have call the getImage method on this code below

```
private void createReportHeader(PdfWriter writer, Document document, String affectedOperation, String timeTaken, String size) throws DocumentException {

    log.debug("Adding header info to document page.");

    PdfPTable headerTable = iTextUtil.createTable(document.getPageSize().getWidth() - 40, 2);

    // add header title & subtitle
    Paragraph paragraph = iTextUtil.createDefaultParagraph(AUTHOR + "\n" + "Business Report on " + affectedOperation + "\n");
    PdfPCell titleCell = iTextUtil.createBorderlessCell();
    titleCell.addElement(paragraph);
    headerTable.addCell(titleCell);
    headerTable.addCell(iTextUtil.createBorderlessCell());

    // add header left cell
    Image logo = getImage("logo", LOGOS);
    logo.scaleToFit(60, 50);
    PdfPCell leftCell = iTextUtil.createBorderlessCell(logo);

    // leftCell.addElement(leftParagraph);
    headerTable.addCell(leftCell);

    // add header right cell
    headerTable.addCell(createHeaderRight(timeTaken, size));

    Rectangle pageSize = document.getPageSize();

    // headerTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 20, document.getPageSize().getHeight() - 10, writer.getDirectContent());
    document.add(headerTable);
}
```

and this method will retrieve an image from a given path if its found in a jar.

```
public Image getImage(String name, String path) {
    Image result = null;
    try {
        File resource = ResourceUtils.getFile(String.format(path, name));
        URL url = resource.toURI().toURL();
        if (url != null)
            result = Image.getInstance(url);
    }
    catch (IOException | BadElementException e) {
        ReportGenerator.log.info("Image file "+name+" not found in path: " +path);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated thanks in advance.